# Upload data, call r script and change data, download using ShinyApp

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-server, reactive

I want to upload a dataframe, call r scipt and apply a function that updates the dataframe, then download it. Can anyone help me?

Let's say this is the function I need to call

```
Identify_IP(dataframe)
return(dataframe')
```

This is Shiny App

```
library(shiny)

source('InflectionP2.R', local = TRUE)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Upload your file"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file',
                    accept = c(".XLS")),

          actionButton("btn", "Update Table")
        ),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('what'))
      )
    ),

    server = function(input, output, session){

      dataframe <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(input$file1))
          return(NULL)
      Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote))
        })

      observeEvent(input$btn, {output$what <- renderTable({dataframe})})
          }
)
)
```

This is what I get

> > Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame

Comment: It was solved by adding () to dataframe at the end in renderTable. and taking off : ,header=.....$quote)